# XPath For Elements With Tag Name ID

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm having trouble retrieving elements values with tag name "Id"
All other elements and even the Parent Node (`//Product`) XPath works perfectly, but for some reason I can't get the Id elements by XPath

I've tried several path queries including:

```
//Product/Id[1]/text()
//Product/Id[1]
//Product[1]/Id[1]/text()
//Product[1]/Id/text()
```

I suspect "Id" is reserved or is that I'm doing something wrong here?

```
...<Product>
              <Id>401057</Id>
              <ProductOrderKey>439138</ProductOrderKey>
              <EffectiveDate>20101102145002</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpiredDate>20370101000000</ExpiredDate>
              <Status>0</Status>
           </Product>
           <Product>
              <Id>420004</Id>
              <ProductOrderKey>439139</ProductOrderKey>
              <EffectiveDate>20101102145002</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpiredDate>20370101000000</ExpiredDate>
              <Status>0</Status>
           </Product>
           <Product>
              <Id>401061</Id>
              <ProductOrderKey>439140</ProductOrderKey>
              <EffectiveDate>20101102145002</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpiredDate>20370101000000</ExpiredDate>
              <Status>0</Status>
           </Product>
           <Product>
              <Id>401008</Id>
              <ProductOrderKey>439141</ProductOrderKey>
              <EffectiveDate>20101102145002</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpiredDate>20370101000000</ExpiredDate>
              <Status>0</Status>
           </Product>
           <Product>
              <Id>420000</Id>
              <ProductOrderKey>439142</ProductOrderKey>
              <EffectiveDate>20101102145023</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpiredDate>20370101000000</ExpiredDate>
              <Status>0</Status>
           </Product>
           <Service>...
```

Comment: I think you have only one `Id` inside your `Product`s, so you should try `//Product[1]/Id` instead...

Comment: [I can't reproduce](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b86f58ccf7d809a5c8083cdecb81255e) and I didn't find anything mentioning `Id` as a reserved token. Maybe you could try whether another XPath implementation works better?

Comment: And the XPath you should use most likely is `//Product/Id` (with or without a trailing `/text()` depending on whether you want the node or its content). No need to add `[1]` when you know there's only one node, and adding it after the `Product` axe will change the behaviour as only the first product will be considered.

Comment: I edited the two additional XPaths into your question. And - I also can't reproduce.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you curated your extract before posting it here, but if there are namespaces in the original they might be the reason why you have problems accessing nodes. It would be easily testable by using the `//Product/*:Id` XPath instead, but if it works it would be best to explicitly address the correct namespace

Comment: @rnxfod, it would be helpful to get you answer if you could post the java code you are using to retrieve the value. A bug could be there in that.

Comment: Thanks everyone - esp. @Aaron, turns out "Id" tag was in a different namespace.
Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
        File inputFile = new File("C:/product.txt");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory
                = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        String expression = "/Products/Product";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Student roll no : "
                        + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Id").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can parse a xml file and get the Id tag value.I hope this will be useful for you.